# mock object that implements gets and sets not defined in interface

Tags: mocking, moq, rhino-mocks

Using Moq, RhinoMocks or a similar framework, is there a way to configure a mock to implement both get and set on all properties of an object even if the interface does not?

I can certainly mock the objects manually, but would prefer to use an isolation framework like Moq or RhinoMocks to avoid creating a bunch of boilerplate classes.

Here's some sample code:

```
//interface to be mocked
public interface IMyObject
{
    string Property1 { set; }
}

//test method code
var mock = Moq.Mock<IMyObject>();

//...some code here to configure all properties on mock to have a get and set...

var mockObject = mock.Object;

ClassUnderTest obj = new ClassUnderTest(mockObject);
obj.MethodUnderTest();

Assert.IsTrue(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(mockObject.Property1));
```

Running the code as is will throw an exception on mockObject.Property1 because the IMyObject.Property1 property lacks the get accessor.

Thanks, DanO

Comment: Why have a property which lacks a getter?

Comment: @Sam - We're implementing the MVP pattern, and some properties on our views (such as those used to fill drop downs) have no use for a getter, so we don't want to force derived types to implement one.  The lack of a getter or setter in properties of the view also provides a cue as to whether the property is designed to handle user input, application output, or both.

Comment: Note that this violates one FxCop guideline: Properties should not be write-only. Using certain complex types (as in the comment under @Steven's answer) might also violate the guideline: Collection properties should be read-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Rhino Mocks, you could set an expectation for the property.  This basically states that you expect the property to be set to a certain value.  Using your example, an example test method body would be this:

var mock = MockRepository.GenerateMock();
    mock.Expect(x => x.Property1 = "Test");

```
var classUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest(mock);
classUnderTest.MethodUnderTest();

mock.VerifyAllExpectations();
```

This would check to see if `Property1` had been set to "Test" at some point between the call to `mock.Expect` and the call to `mock.MethodUnderTest` (technically, `Property1` could be set in the constructor of `ClassUnderTest`).

In order to test that the property was set and ignore what it was actually set to, just chain `IgnoreArguments` to the return of the `Expect` call, like so:

mock.Expect(x => x.Property1 = "Test1").IgnoreArguments();

One way to test more complex write-only properties is to use the `GetArgumentsForCallsMadeOn` method.  This allows you to retrieve a list of the arguments passed to each "call" of the property.  The code to do this would be like the following:

var mock = MockRepository.GenerateMock();

```
var classUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest(mock);
classUnderTest.MethodUnderTest();

//the argument in the Action is ignored, so just use null
//Property1 is of type List<string>
var arguments = mock.GetArgumentsForCallsMadeOn(x => x.Property1 = null);

//arguments[0] contains the list of arguments for the first "call" of the
//property the first index (0) of that would contain the first argument
var firstCallArguments = arguments[0];
var firstArgument = (List<string>)firstCallArguments[0];
Assert.AreEqual(3, firstArgument.Count);
```

I am sure that Moq has similar functionality if you'd like to use that, instead.

Comment: Thanks!  What about with complex types?  Let's say instead of checking a string for a particular value, you wanted to check if a list contained any times (e.g. x.Property2.Count() > 0)

Comment: I added the details on how to check more complex scenarios and learned something new in the process!

Answer (score 4):

```
public class Test
{
    public void AssertOneElement()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<IMyObject>();
        var list = default(IList<int>);

        mock.SetupSet(x => x.Property1 = It.IsAny<IList<int>>())
            .Callback<IList<int>>(value => list = value);

        // Fails
        mock.Object.Property1 = new List<int>();

        // Succeeds
        // mock.Object.Property1 = new List<int>(new[] { 1 });

        Debug.Assert(list != null);
        Debug.Assert(list.Count == 1, "Called with a list that did not contain a single element!");
    }
}

public interface IMyObject
{
    IList<int> Property1 { set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Moq, this works:

```
var mock = new Mock<IMyObject>();

// test code goes here

// Note single equals sign, not double equals
mock.VerifySet(x => x.Property1 = "expected");
```

SetupAllProperties does NOT work.

Answer (score 1):

For list:

```
var mock = new Mock<IMyObject>();

// your test code

mock.VerifySet(x => x.Property1 = It.Is<IList<int>>(l => l != null && l.Count > 0));
```